# Chars in do while loop conditions

Tags: c++, char, do-while

I am having trouble with the last do while loop in my code. I have conditions set to stop the look when Y, N, y, or n are entered but even if those values are entered the loops continues to run and continue to ask for a Y or N. In debugging it seems that the Ascii value for the character is also stored in the variable? What do I need to change to have the do while loop end when there is an input of any of those 4 characters?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>``

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
  int numberOfShapes, i, j, k, rectangleBase, rectangleHeight;
  char star = '*';
  char filled;

  do
   {
    cout << "Enter the integer between 6 and 20 that you would like to be the base of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> rectangleBase;

   }while (rectangleBase < 6 || rectangleBase > 20);

  rectangleHeight = rectangleBase / 2;
  do
   {
    cout << "Enter the number of shapes you would like to draw(Greater than 0 and less than or equal to 10: ";
    cin >> numberOfShapes;
   } while (numberOfShapes <= 0 || numberOfShapes > 10);

  do
  {
    cout << "Would you like a filled shape? [Y or N]: ";
    cin >> filled;
  } while (filled != 'Y' || filled != 'N' || filled != 'y' || filled != 'n');
```

Comment: Your coding style is ... improveable. Please learn about formatting.

Comment: `filled` can't be 'Y', 'N', 'y' and 'n' at the same time, so at least 3 of the comparisons are always true.

Comment: Some working environments can catch this. For example, anything that integrates with clang-tidy (e.g., CLion) will be able to give *warning: logical expression is always true*

Comment: Please see [Creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you have provided more code than needed to reproduce the problem, as well as  a code sample that does not compile.

Comment: Consider a function -- `bool isValid(char c) {switch(c) {case 'Y':case 'y':case 'N':case 'n':return true;}return false;}`  -- Then it would simply be `while (!isValid(filled));`

Answer (score 4):

Your loop end condition is wrong:

```
while (filled != 'Y' || filled != 'N' || filled != 'y' || filled != 'n');
```

consider that the value is `'y'` then your condition will be:

```
(true || true || false || true)
```

which evaluates to `true`.

Change to:

```
while (filled != 'Y' && filled != 'N' && filled != 'y' && filled != 'n');
```

Then it will be:

```
-> 'y' (true && true && false && true) -> false
-> 'l' (true && true && true && true) -> true
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `&&` not `||`:

```
} while (filled != 'Y' && filled != 'N' && filled != 'y' && filled != 'n');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write it as you say it, perhaps it would be more clear and will help to avoid these mistakes:

```
do
{
    cout << "Would you like a filled shape? [Y or N]: ";
    cin >> filled;
    if (filled == 'Y' || filled == 'N' || filled == 'y' || filled == 'n')
       break;
} 
while (true);
```